# Search for word in ListBox written on InputBox (C# VS)

Tags: c#, winforms, search, listbox

I have a ListBox with words and I need to click a button that opens an InputBox where I can search for a word and the program will run the ListBox and highlight the word I wrote in the InputBox if it's there. If the program reaches the end of the list and doesn't find the word then I'll get a MessageBox saying the word I'm looking for isn't there. I need to use some sort of cycle for this program.

I know how to make the button, InputBox and the error MessageBox, but I don't know how to do the searching and cycle.

I've read a lot of similar questions here but I don't think any of them return the result I'm looking for.

Can anyone help me? Or redirect me to a post with the answer?

This is for Winforms.

Comment: Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @aybe Winforms. Sorry for not refering that, didn't knew WPF was a thing

Comment: FWIW from UX standpoint, the way you want makes it pretty convoluted for the end user.

Comment: @aybe Yeah I know, but it's an exercise from my Informatic Aplications class in HS. My teacher isn't a very good one unfortunately.

Comment: See if my answer helps somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should get you on track, it's pretty much self-explanative:

- whenever text changes
- find matching items in list
- select them

[image]

Code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var text = textBox.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        return; // nothing to search for

    const StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase; // maybe change this

    // find items matching text

    var indices = new List<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = listBox1.Items[i];

        if (string.Equals(item?.ToString(), text, comparison))
            indices.Add(i);
    }

    // select them in list

    if (!indices.Any())
        return;

    listBox1.SelectedIndices.Clear();

    foreach (var index in indices) 
        listBox1.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
}
```

Of course, list selection mode has to be multiple for it to work properly.

Also, you will need to clear selection if there are no matches so as to not leave the UI in an ambiguous state (not done).

Comment: Thank you! It worked well, I just had to adapt to InputBox and insert the error message. Thanks again!

Comment: Great job, you welcome!

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing someone's homework. I know these tiny little assignments are fun to do, but don't you think it would be better to give the OP some hints to get him/her going? Take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well, I intentionally didn't match the question, he got a good hint, managed to integrate it in his setup and hopefully he learned something and not blindly copied the result, I hope so... I think learning by the example is good, isn't that what they're supposed to do in school ? Imagine if I'd task you to make some bread and throw at you, flour, water and an oven without further explanations; most likely you'll fail and more importantly you'll get bored IMO.